# ViewState won't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code to try to use viewstate to save a variable for postback.  When post back occurs the SrString value is nothing.  I have set the ViewState value at the dropdownlist index chane event and set the variable equal ot ViewState("SrString") at page in the if ispostback block.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
'Page Load

If IsPostBack Then
    SrString = ViewState("SrString")
End If

'DropDownList Index change event

Protected Sub ByteDataFile_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ByteDataFile.SelectedIndexChanged
    ViewState("SrString") = SrString
End Sub
```

My web config file is correct, because I have other pages in the web site that works with the viewstate fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is EnableViewState set to false in your page directive or on the control itself?

Comment: Did you add the SrString with ViewState.Add(SrString)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Page_Load is executed before ByteDataFile_SelectedIndexChanged.

ASP.NET Page life cycle always executes Page_Load first and then it handles events like clicks and SelectedIndexChanged, so when you say `SrString = ViewState("SrString")` in Page_Load, the `ViewState("SrString") = SrString` line hasn't been called yet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Assuming you get the value for SrString from dropDownList's selected item, you just need to get that in Page_Load, something similar to this:

```
If IsPostBack Then
    'I got this from your comment in the other answer, but I suppose LineNo and FileNameID are comming somehow from the drop downlist, right?
    ViewState("SrString") = "\\...\soi\Bytewise\Line " & LineNo & "\Text Files\" & FileNameID
End If
```

Another thing you need to be sure is that the DropDownList has its AutoPostBack property set to true, otherwise the page won't postback when you change the selection.

For this kind of thing I think you should use a HiddenField instead of the ViewState.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/298/hiddenfield/

Comment: This could also be the source of the problem.

Comment: This means I am really confused how the dropdownlist change event works.  How does the page load know the changed value if it goes to page load first even after this change?

Comment: In Page_Load you can use yourDropDownList.SelectedIndex and it will have the updated value.

Comment: Yes, but the dropdownlist only contains the file name not the entire path.

Comment: OK.  Let me understand completely.  If i use the 'SrString = ByteDataFile.SelectedItem.Value'  I don't need to use the ViewState("SrString") at all do I?  The autopostback is set to "True".

Comment: OK.  I think I know what to do.  I will try you suggestion.  However, I am confused as to the purpose and application of ViewState().  How do you get this to pass a value for a variable (not control) to the page load?

Comment: ViewState's purpose is to keep track of the controls state through poastbacks (size, color, layout). ViewState don't pass values, it just hold a bag of values of its own and you can access them to decide what to do on PostBack. For example, you can set a variables's value or call a method. Look at my final edit.

Comment: You can select this answer as the solution by checking the mark located below the points. Left hand from my answer's beginning. That would give me 15 points :D

Answer (score 2):

Where is `SrString` set? From the code you posted, it is only ever assigned to or from the ViewState, and therefore will always be null.

Some more explanation:

```
If IsPostBack Then
    SrString = ViewState("SrString")
End If

'DropDownList Index change event

Protected Sub ByteDataFile_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ByteDataFile.SelectedIndexChanged
    ViewState("SrString") = SrString
End Sub
```

In page load, we set SrString to the value in the view state.

In your changed event, we set the ViewState to the value of SrString.

However, at no time is SrString ever set to a value, so you're just passing a null value around. There needs to be, somewhere:

```
SrString = 'some value from somewhere besides the viewstate.
```

Given:

a=b

b=a

And no other assignment, the value will never change.

Comment: SrString is not a control.  It is a variable set during the DropDownList change event.  I did not use ViewState.Add(SrString) - does this go in the dropdownlist change event?

Comment: I originally set the value for SrString during page load - this is a string for files search (path and file name).  Then I have the file name during the DropDownList change event.  This changed string is what i am trying to pass back to the page load during post back.

Comment: In this case, you need to look at dailoquio's answer.

Comment: Protected Sub ByteDataFile_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ByteDataFile.SelectedIndexChanged  Dim SrString As String = "\\...\soi\Bytewise\Line " & LineNo & "\Text Files\" & FileNameID  ViewState("SrString") = SrString  End Sub         The initial value during initial page load is set in the same way just different values for LineNO and FileNameID.